# Как сделать fetch локального JSON?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как сделать fetch локального JSON?

Пытаюсь так:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const onFetch = async () => {
    const req = await fetch("./data.json");
    return req.json();
  };

  const onMap = () => {
    onFetch()
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));
  };

  return <div className="App">{onMap()}</div>;
}
```

Но получаю

***SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0***

Answer (score 1):

потому что вы два раза вызываете преобразование результата фетча в json на строке 7 и 12

Comment: Убрал преобразование с 12 строки, ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Для этого нужно запустить бэкэнд с методами работы с файловой системой. Затем вашим фетч делать запрос на бэк, который будет считывать файл отправлять.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем это вообще делать?
Можно просто сделать импорт

```
import data from "./data.json";
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, можно через импорт получить `json`, а в вашем варианте к `fetch` запросу нужно указать полный путь и запустить через локальный сервер(`await fetch("http://localhost:3000/data.json")`)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно переместить файл data.json в папку public